Restoring Cassandra from snapshot getting an Error
We are running JanusGraph along with two clusters of Cassandra and Elasticsearch in Docker.
version: "3"

services:
  janusgraph:
    image: local-janusgraph:latest
    container_name: jce-janusgraphdb
    environment:
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cql-es
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: jce-cassandra-1,jce-cassandra-2
      janusgraph.index.search.hostname: jce-elastic-1,jce-elastic-2
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    volumes:
      - janusgraph-data:/var/lib/janusgraph  # Mounts a volume to JanusGraph

  cassandra-1:
    image: cassandra:3
    container_name: jce-cassandra-1
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "jce-cassandra-1,jce-cassandra-2"
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: "janusgraph-cluster"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    volumes:
      - cassandra1-data:/var/lib/cassandra  # Mounts a volume to Cassandra

  cassandra-2:
    image: cassandra:3
    container_name: jce-cassandra-2
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "jce-cassandra-1,jce-cassandra-2"
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: "janusgraph-cluster"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    volumes:
      - cassandra2-data:/var/lib/cassandra  # Mounts a volume to Cassandra

  elasticsearch-1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    container_name: jce-elastic-1
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "network.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=jce-elastic-1,jce-elastic-2"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data  # Mounts a volume to Elasticsearch

  elasticsearch-2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    container_name: jce-elastic-2
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "network.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=jce-elastic-1,jce-elastic-2"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data  # Mounts a volume to Elasticsearch

networks:
  jce-network:

volumes:
  janusgraph-data:
  cassandra1-data:
  cassandra2-data:
  esdata1:
  esdata2:

Dockerfile as follow
FROM docker.io/janusgraph/janusgraph:latest

WORKDIR /opt/janusgraph
USER root

# Copy configuration files
COPY janusgraph-server.yaml /opt/janusgraph/conf/janusgraph-server.yaml
COPY empty-sample.groovy /opt/janusgraph/scripts/empty-sample.groovy
COPY janusgraph-keyspace-one.properties /opt/janusgraph/conf/janusgraph-keyspace-one.properties
COPY janusgraph-keyspace-two.properties /opt/janusgraph/conf/janusgraph-keyspace-two.properties

# Set ownership for the entire conf directory in one step
# RUN chown -R janusgraph:janusgraph /opt/janusgraph/conf

USER janusgraph

WORKDIR /opt/janusgraph

We have two keyspaces named keyspace_one and keyspace_two, and we are trying to take a snapshot of the keyspace keyspace_one by following the command.
docker exec -it jce-cassandra-1 nodetool snapshot keyspace_one

We have successfully created the snapshot folder, and everything is functioning properly. Now, we are attempting to restore the backed-up snapshot to keyspace_two. To do this, we copied the snapshot data to the keyspace_two folder as outlined in the documentation. Next, we executed the command to refresh the keyspace.
nodetool refresh keyspace_two edgestore

We are encountering the following error:
root@cec647038c56:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh keyspace_two edgestore
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.PartitionColumns$Builder.add(PartitionColumns.java:161)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SerializationHeader$Component.toHeader(SerializationHeader.java:340)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:522)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.loadNewSSTables(ColumnFamilyStore.java:801)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.loadNewSSTables(ColumnFamilyStore.java:739)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.loadNewSSTables(StorageService.java:5404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:276)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Is there any configuration or command that we might be overlooking?

Edited:
We attempted to obtain fresh graph data, took a snapshot of keyspace_one, and then dropped the keyspace by running the following command.
DROP Keyspace_two ;

We then recreated the keyspace by executing the following command.
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace_one WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};

We executed the following command to recreate the schema and copy/restore the data from a snapshot to the keyspace folder for keyspace_one. The command is as follows:

Restore

root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd edgestore-926ec1209d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77 && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd edgestore_lock_-92aa91a09d9311ef8a912791ce557ac0 && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd graphindex-93097a809d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/ && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd graphindex_lock_-9343eb709d9311ef8a912791ce557ac0 && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd janusgraph_ids-9213cfe09d9311ef8a912791ce557ac0 && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd systemlog-93d52ef09d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77 && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd system_properties-91c6c1509d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/ && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd system_properties_lock_-942cebe09d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/ && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cd txlog-93989b209d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77 && cp ./snapshots/1731070358151/* . && cd -



Schema creation

root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f edgestore-926ec1209d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f edgestore_lock_-92aa91a09d9311ef8a912791ce557ac0/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f graphindex-93097a809d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f graphindex_lock_-9343eb709d9311ef8a912791ce557ac0/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f janusgraph_ids-9213cfe09d9311ef8a912791ce557ac0/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f systemlog-93d52ef09d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f system_properties-91c6c1509d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f system_properties_lock_-942cebe09d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/schema.cql >> null
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# cqlsh -f txlog-93989b209d9311efa9ba31a44f2d5d77/schema.cql >> null



Nodetool refresh

root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two edgestore
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two edgestore_lock_
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two graphindex
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two graphindex_lock_
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two janusgraph_ids
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two systemlog
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two system_properties
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two system_properties_lock_
root@379dc32f07c7:/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace_two# nodetool refresh -- keyspace_two txlog

After checking the node count of the newly restored data, it is not the same as the node count before the snapshot.
Node count for before snapshot
gremlin> g1.V().count();
==>3354

Node count after restore snapshot
gremlin> g1.V().count();
==>1592

We attempted to fetch some data from the restored keyspace, but we encountered the following error:
gremlin> g1.V().hasLabel("People").values("title");
Could not find type for id: 60941
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
java.lang.NullPointerException: Could not find type for id: 60941
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:994)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.vertices.JanusGraphSchemaVertex.name(JanusGraphSchemaVertex.java:73)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.label(AbstractVertex.java:122)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.system.ImplicitKey.computeProperty(ImplicitKey.java:94)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.executeImplicitKeyQuery(BasicVertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:236)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.vertex.VertexCentricQueryBuilder.properties(VertexCentricQueryBuilder.java:119)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.ElementHelper.getValues(ElementHelper.java:48)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.condition.PredicateCondition.evaluate(PredicateCondition.java:72)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.condition.And.evaluate(And.java:55)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.graph.GraphCentricQuery.matches(GraphCentricQuery.java:157)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor.lambda$getFilterIterator$2(QueryProcessor.java:138)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.CloseableIteratorUtils$1.computeNext(CloseableIteratorUtils.java:51)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.nextInternal(ResultSetIterator.java:55)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.<init>(ResultSetIterator.java:45)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor.iterator(QueryProcessor.java:68)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.graph.GraphCentricQueryBuilder.lambda$iterables$1(GraphCentricQueryBuilder.java:240)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.JanusGraphStep.lambda$executeGraphCentricQuery$2(JanusGraphStep.java:203)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.util.ProfiledIterator.<init>(ProfiledIterator.java:36)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.JanusGraphStep.executeGraphCentricQuery(JanusGraphStep.java:203)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.JanusGraphStep.lambda$null$0(JanusGraphStep.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.JanusGraphStep.lambda$new$1(JanusGraphStep.java:106)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.GraphStep.processNextStart(GraphStep.java:158)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.step.JanusGraphMultiQueryStep.processNextStart(JanusGraphMultiQueryStep.java:111)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.hasNext(ExpandableStepIterator.java:47)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.NoOpBarrierStep.processAllStarts(NoOpBarrierStep.java:67)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.NoOpBarrierStep.processNextStart(NoOpBarrierStep.java:56)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.FlatMapStep.processNextStart(FlatMapStep.java:48)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:155)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.hasNext(DefaultTraversal.java:192)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractOpProcessor.handleIterator(AbstractOpProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractEvalOpProcessor.lambda$evalOpInternal$6(AbstractEvalOpProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:283)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
gremlin> 


@aaron, we tried as you suggested, but we're getting this error. I suspect we are missing the backup and restore of index data in Elasticsearch.

Just a thought, but this might only work if the target keyspace name is the same as the source.
In the directory of the snapshot files, have a look at the schema.cql file that was generated. Try setting all references to keyspace_1 in that file to keyspace_2, and run the refresh again.

Thank you for your response. I will try it out and let you know how it goes.

I followed your suggestion and updated the post regarding the error I encountered after the restore.

i have created the gitlab issue for the same
